# Facebook SDK iOS attribution/conversion data fetching

Tags: ios, facebook

Im looking into Facebook Marketing API and specifically attribution/conversion data tracking.

What i want to do is replace the AppsFlyer Im currently using for tracking app installs, conversion data etc. with Facebook Attribution.

But it seems like i cannot fetch/retrieve the data from the Facebook SDK, it seems to only be available on the Facebook Attribution dashboard.

My goal is to fetch that data and send it to my own backend for analytics.

In their documentation i found this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/attribution

but it seems to be something else, more generalised reports...

Is this even possible? Or am i stuck with using Facebook dashboard to view this data?